# HTML embutido no C# dot net visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

Preciso gerar um HTML dinâmico em uma aplicação C# implementado no Visual Studio.

No caso, preciso exibir a tag `li` conforme usuário logado (session).

O código é:

```
<%if (Session["usuario"] != null) {
    <li><a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Paginas/Contratos.aspx") %>">
        <img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/chama.png") %>" class="chama" />
        <span>Contratos</span></a><br class="clear" />
    </li>
}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer o seguinte:

```
<li> <%= ((Usuario)Session["usuario"]).Nome %> <li/>
```

Onde `Usuario` é o tipo do dado que contém na `Session` "usuario" e o `Nome` é a propriedade que encontra-se na classe `Usuario`.

Comment: Guilherme, obrigado pela atenção. Na realidade preciso o seguinte:

        <%if (Session["usuario"] != null) 
          { 
        <li><a href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Paginas/Contratos.aspx") %>">
            <img src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/chama.png") %>" class="chama" /><span>Contratos</span></a><br class="clear" />
        </li>

          }
         %>